# Does it make sense to impute missing covariate data when the imputed value is a function of other covariates in the regression model?

Tags: regression, modeling, missing-data, panel-data, data-imputation

We are building a model that adjusts for standard covariates (e.g., age, gender) and for the outcome at baseline.  It would be ideal to adjust for each subject's baseline value like so: 
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1*{\rm age} + \beta_2*{\rm gender} + \beta_3*{\rm baseline}
$$
However, we don't have baseline measures for everyone.  There is a standard clinical estimation of $Y$ (current and baseline) as a nonlinear function of age and gender and also a measure $X$ (which we do have on everyone), i.e., $\text{Estimated Baseline} = f(X,\ {\rm age},\ {\rm gender}) $.

Does it make more sense to model $Y$ by including the raw value $X$ or the function of $X$?  For example:

\begin{align}
Y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1*{\rm age} + \beta_2*{\rm gender} + \beta_3*X  \\
Y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1*{\rm age} + \beta_2*{\rm gender} + \beta_3*f(X,\ {\rm age},\ {\rm gender})
\end{align}

The estimated function is not a great estimate, but it is closer to the baseline measure.

Comment: By "... and *it* is also a (nonlinear) function of age and gender...", I assume you mean that the best estimate of the estimated baseline value is a function of age & gender, not that X is a function of age & gender. Is that right?

Comment: Correct -- X is a different measure that is associated to our outcome, and cheaper to collect.  Previous studies have published an estimating equation of the form:
$$
 est(Y) = (X^a)(age^b)(c*male + d*female) = f(X,age,gender) \\ 
$$
Since X is easy and cheap to collect, most people just use this.  So we could adjust our model for someone's estimated baseline, but that's just a function of other variables already in the model.

Comment: I tweaked that phrasing; please make sure it still says what you want. I think this is a great question, I'm interested in seeing what people will say. It seems to me that it taps several issues, including missing data, imputation schemes, measurement error, multicollinearity, & the connection b/t the modeling decisions made & the nature of the question you are trying to ask.

Comment: Huh -- I didn't actually think of this as an imputation question, but I guess it is the same idea.  Using the estimated baseline is like doing a single imputation, but based on an external dataset.